# Interpreting the distance between Boolean vectors

Tags: vectors, computer-science

Our book has this exercise:

> Distance between Boolean vectors. Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are Boolean $n$-vectors, which means that each of their entries is either $0$ or $1$. What is their distance $\|x-y\|?$

I think I've got it, but is there a simpler interpretation?

My attempt:

Whenever $x_i$ and $y_i$ (for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$) are the same, we end up with a $0$ for $x_i - y_i$. Whenever they are different, we always get a $1$. My interpretation is that it's the square root of the number of bits that differ between $x$ and $y$.

But what is the significance of such a measure? Wouldn't computing the square of the distance be a more meaningful computation? Also, wouldn't it be faster to just do a pairwise bit comparison?

Comment: It's kind of difficult to interpret your question, as the notation $\|\cdot\|$ can mean multiple things, depending on context. Do you have a defined norm you're using?

Comment: Just the Euclidean norm @AdrianKeister

Comment: Then you've just got $$\|x-y\|=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)\right)^{1/2}.$$

Comment: Yes, but I guess I should clarify: The problem isn't asking for it literally, but rather wants an interpretation. Or rather, I interpreted it.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything more to it than what you've already got. It's the Euclidean distance! I would say that in binary world, there are other measures, such as Hamming distance, that can sometimes be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am going through the same book and exercise at the moment and my interpretation is as per the previous comments on this post. However, it also seems that: $$0 \le ||x-y|| \le \sqrt n$$

i.e. assume that all bits differ, the distance can be at most $\sqrt n$.